# Parse JSON to POJO with jackson @JsonDeserialize @JsonCreator

Tags: android, parsing, jackson, retrofit

There is a example json response i.e.

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "test_name",
    "email" : "test@test.com"
}
```

Ideally the POJO for this response using Jackson should be something like this

```
class User {

    String id;
    String name;
    String email;

    // getter setter
}
```

But I want this response to be parsed in a POJO such

```
class User {

    IdName idName;
    String email;

    // getter setter
}
```

where IdName is :

```
class IdName {

    String id;
    String name;

    // getter setter
}
```

The POJO's structure cannot be changed, so want to achieve this through Jackson annotations

Comment: Why? Why your POJO can't be changed?

Comment: Because **IdName** serves as a Base for a lot of classes and this same problem is there in a lot of classes so I cannot keep making new POJO for every time

Comment: If your JSON responses are different then you have to create new POJO class every time. That's not a big deal.

Comment: No, jackson can take care of dynamic responses with same POJO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to working through Gson only. Gson provides an interface **JsonDeserializer** through which we can provide our own custom deserializing logic to the whichever class we want.

As specific to the case I asked below would be the classes :

```
class User {

    @Expose
    IdName idName;
    @Expose
    String email;

    // getter setter
}
```

where IdName is :

```
class IdName {

    @Expose
    String id;
    @Expose
    String name;

    // getter setter
}
```

Custom Deserialzer -

```
public class TempDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

@Override
public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    int id = jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt();
    String name = jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();

    IdName idName = new IdName(id, name);

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(jsonObject.get("email").getAsString());
    user.setIdName(idName);
    return user;
}
}
```

This would now return a User object with IdName object set from response values.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Implementation of POJO is to use all attributes of that object in private and initializing them using constructors and then using getters and setters.

Most of the open source libraries are designed to return data from this format only, If you want to change this make a new class and tweak the object from there.

Comment: POJO's structure cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Gson for that. Using Gson you can convert JSON to Object and vice-versa. Below is a sample:

**From JSON to Object:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(myJson, MyObject.class);
```

**From Object to JSON:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

Comment: Be more specific as to how Gson would achieve such thing. I have tried Gson.

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON String is like below than you can get your expected POJO

```
{
    "IdName":{ "id" : 1,
    "name" : "test_name"},
    "email" : "test@test.com"
}
```

Comment: Yes i know but the JSON response is not like this.

Comment: ya but using your json string you can not achive your ecpected pojo

Comment: As stated in the question, POJO structure also cannot be changed as IdName is a base class for others.

Comment: but using that json string how can achive  expected pojo ?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Modify your json response ask your backend developer to do so.

   ```
   {
   "IdName":
   {"id" : 1,
   "name" : "test_name"
   },
   "email" : "test@test.com"
    }
   ```

   2. Manually create IdName pojo,assign value to id& name and then change the pojo.

      IdName idName=new IdName(id,name)

      user.idName=idName

Comment: Firstly, modifying the response is never a solution.
Secondly if I have to parse response manually then why I would be asking for a solution with jackson